# How to write "for x in list" in Java?

Tags: java, list, syntax, for-loop, foreach

I was wondering how to express a certain type of for loop in Java.

In Python I would use:

```
for x in lst1:
       return 10
```

How would I do this in Java?

```
I know for the range for-loops, I use
for(int i=0; i<100; j++) {
   return "asdf"
}
```

I just want to know how to do the other type of loop

Comment: It is called an ["(Enhanced) For-Each Loop"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

Comment: Doing an unconditional `return <constant>` as the body of a `for` loop is kind of silly. Even if you get the `for` loop completely wrong, as long as it has at least one loop to do, it'll still work exactly the same…

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
int[] myints = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
for(int i : myints) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: does lst1 represent arrays in python ??

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR: That's a variable name. It could represent anything. I'm guessing from context.

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR: It doesn't actually matter whether `lst1` is a `list` (Python's rough equivalent to a Java array), or some other kind of iterable; the same `for x in lst1:` loop works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] lst1 = {1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9};    
for (int x : lst1){
    return 10;
}
```

That's--as far as I'm aware--the exact conversion of your python code. I recently did a [video tutorial on iterating through a list](https://youtu.be/6e6IueITWp4?t=407) that you and other's will most likely benefit from watching.

Good luck!